# What to do when you have much permissions with a binary system?

Tags: php, permissions, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm planning to use a binary system to handle my permissions, like this:

```
<?php
const POST = 1;
const DELETE = 2;
const UPDATE = 4;
const READ = 8;
const ADMIN = 16;
const ADD_PRODUCT = 32;
const DELETE_PRODUCT = 64;
const ADD_BLOG = 128;


$permission = decbin('5');

if ($permission & POST) { echo "POST <br />"; }
if ($permission & DELETE) { echo "DELETE <br />"; }
if ($permission & UPDATE) { echo "UPDATE <br />"; }
if ($permission & READ) { echo "READ <br />"; }
if ($permission & ADMIN) { echo "ADMIN <br />"; }

?>
```

With a few permissions, this will work well. But what if i have, lets say, 40 different permissions? Then I need to add up some really big numbers, which is a pain in the ass.

Is there any other way?

Any info or help will be greatly appriciated!

Comment: When you say "binary system", you are really utilizing ["bit masks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

Comment: If you have 40 permissions, don't use a bitmask to store them, at least not in your code. Make it data-driven.

Comment: Of course I would store them in a database, this was just for example. I forgot to mention that, sorry. Can you explain a bit more about what you mean with data-driven?

Comment: @BlueCola You would not practically be able to store more than 32 permissions with an integer bitmask if you wanted compatibility with 32-bit systems. You can use binary strings to do this though, and it's the smallest way to store the data, but it's not searchable. If all you want to do is store users with a bitfield of their permissions just use the bitmask approach. But let's say I want to find all users who have a specific permission - this will be a very slow operation as the database will have to perform a bitwise operation on each row instead of looking for values in a specific column.

Comment: It'll likely be cheaper to do a Mysql Lookup instead of doing this with BIT Flags, so you could have a "permissions" table which had the permissions. But better still, look into an ACL system where a user is given a role and that role has permissions attached with it - less duplication and you don't need to maintain a mapper table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use hex to define the constants - it's much easier to type.

2) Break up the separate permissions into different user roles.

e.g.

```
const BLOG_POST      = 0x01;
const BLOG_DELETE    = 0x02;
const BLOG_UPDATE    = 0x04;
const BLOG_READ      = 0x08;
const BLOG_SUBSCRIBE = 0x10;

const ADMIN_IS_ADMIN       = 0x01;
const ADMIN_ADD_PRODUCT    = 0x02;
const ADMIN_DELETE_PRODUCT = 0x04;
const ADMIN_ADD_BLOG       = 0x08;
```

Even when you get up to large numbers, they're still easy to type

```
const ADMIN_SOME_PERMISSION   = 0x1000;
const ADMIN_SOME_PERMISSION2  = 0x2000;
```